# Test Web Service Client with spring MockWebServiceServer

Tags: spring, webservice-client

I am currently trying to test my web service clients with spring MockWebServiceServer as the real web service servers are not exposed yet. I have been following the spring doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html but still getting some issue like below:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
               at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:545)
               at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:386)
               at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:380)
               at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:372)
```

I believe the error has something to do with the WebServiceTemplate I autowired into my WS client as below. Since I am using a MockWebServiceServer, I do not think a real HTTP connection is needed, but why it is complaining as such? Do I still need to start up my tomcat server to make the localhost:8080 accessible even using the MockWebServiceServer?

```
<bean id="vehicleOrderConfirmationWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
         <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
         <property name="marshaller" ref="vehicleOrderConfirmationMarshaller" />
         <property name="unmarshaller" ref="vehicleOrderConfirmationMarshaller" />
         <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080"/>
</bean>
```

Anyone could suggest?

Comment: Could you please post your test client class code?

Answer (score 0):

the mocked server does not need a real http connection. it mocks the MessageSender.
how did you create you mocked web server ? below usage must be enough a real mocked server

MockWebServiceServer.createServer(vehicleOrderConfirmationWebServiceTemplate);

Comment: I tried it before but no working, I guess I still missed something there....that's why later I chose to built up a whole real-mock-up web service server to test my clients.

Answer (score 0):

If your client class extends the `WebServiceGatewaySupport` like the example given by the [Spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html), make sure you have set the `WebServiceTemplate` by using the inherited `setWebServiceTemplate()` method.

```
@Autowired
public CustomerClient (WebServiceTemplate customerClientWebServiceTemplate) {
  setWebServiceTemplate(customerClientWebServiceTemplate);
}
```